# EJS: <%= versus <%-

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm using EJS with a Node.js web server I'm building.  I see many EJS examples that sometimes use `<%=` when outputting HTML or strings, while other examples (sometimes within the same template) use `<%-`.

I tried to reference [the EJS](https://ejs.co/#docs) docs and [getting started guide](https://ejs.co/#install), but both gave no info about the `<%-` notation.  Also, my Google search attempts yielded nothing useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The version of EJS you're likely using in Node is not the same as the version you see on Google code; in the Node version, `<%=` escapes the HTML going into the buffer, while `<%-` does not. <sup>[source](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#features)</sup>

Comment: Hi, I was searching for the same question but what does "escapes the HTML going into the buffer" means? What is the buffer?

Comment: @holyxiaoxin Normally, it's the buffer that will be flushed down the socket to the user's browser.

Comment: @holyxiaoxin 'k &#160; k' inside <%= will be written as 'k &amp;#160; k'. It would be HTML escaped. Inside <%-  it will result in a space 'k k'

Answer (score 20):

From http://ejs.co/:

```
<% 'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output
<%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template
```

Comment: This is exactly what is in the documentation. Can you an example of what it neans

Comment: This solved a bug for me... Using window.open('<%= url %>') and passing a url with a query string was encoding the &.

The fix was simply change `=` to `-`

Answer (score 7):

`<%= *param* %>` is  use for transfer data from view to controller and vice versa

while `<%- %>` is to include other code

For my project is

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `<%=` you if would render some variables that holds a string that holds HTML code, it would not render that HTML code but render it as text to avoid cross-site scripting attacks.
With a minus ( `<%-` ) you can avoid this, and really render the HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

1)Option One: an ejs file is importing a variable called "noob" which holds for example a req.body value.
`<p><%= noob %></p>`

2)Option two: an ejs file importing a partial template called "myPartial.ejs" which is inside "partials" folder.
`<p><%- include("./partials/myPartial") %></p>`

3)Option three: an ejs file is using javascript code:

```
<p>
<% while (i < 10) { %>
  myVar += "The number is " + i;
  i++;
<% } %>
</p>
```