# EJS: <% vs <%- --> What's the difference

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

The [EJS documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs) summarizes the difference between <% and <%- as below:

> <% 'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output
>
> <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
>
> <%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template

However, I noticed that I get the same HTML output whether I use <% or <%-, as below

```
<%# Include header %>
<% include partials/header %> //Using <%

<h1>This is the home page</h1>
<p>Some content goes here</p>

<%# Include footer %>
<%- include partials/footer %> //using <%-
```

This is my header.ejs file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app.css">
    <title>Demo App</title>
</head>
<body>
```

I've already checked out the following quesion ([EJS: <%= versus <%-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024840/ejs-versus)) but it didn't explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%-` and `<%` tags have different purposes, the first one is simply for unescaped output:

```
const template = '<%- user %>';
ejs.render(template, { user: 'Alice' }); // renders "Alice"
```

But let's say there are many users, in this case it may be required to use some flow control structure to iterate over users, this is when `<%` is used:

```
const template2 = '<% users.map(user => { %> <%- user -%> <% }) %>';
ejs.render(template, { users: ['Alice', 'Bob'] }); // renders "Alice  Bob"
```

As you can verify, in these examples tags `<%-` and `<%` have different behavior and are not interchangeable.

---

The case you have described with `include` is pretty special. In my opinion, the expected behavior would be not to output the `partials/header` (with `<%`) as it is a simple template (not a flow control).

This is how it works with modern `include` syntax, i.e if you try to `include` the header using:

```
<% include("partials/header") %>
```

instead of

```
<% include partials/header %>
```

you will see that there is no output.

As for the legacy `include` syntax, it appears that `ejs` treats it equally inside `<%` and `<%-` tags. Should you want to investigate this matter further, inspecting the library source code may be helpful: https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/lib/ejs.js#L713

Or you can simply prefer the new `include` syntax which appears to provide more consistent behavior.

Comment: Thanks @antonku. Did a little research on what you said, and in the 2 different approaches to include --> `<% include("partials/header") %>` calls on the include JS function, while the legacy approach `<% include partials/header %>` is a preprocessor directive, which explains the difference in behaviour. As per the [syntax docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/docs/syntax.md#including-other-files) :  -_You most probably should not use the -%> ending tag on an include directive, as it trims the whitespace after the included file._

Comment: @MohitBajaj Thanks for sharing the additional information